# How to put initial snapshot data with the phone sign in method

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out how to put initial data into Firestore when the user signs in using their phone #(And keep their data stored when they log out and sign in again). If anyone has worked with the email sign-in method you will know that *createUserWithEmailAndPassword* runs only once when the user registers a new account.

But for the google sign-in method and phone sign-in method, it has only one function that runs every time when they sign up, so every time when they log out and sign back in, their data gets overwritten with the initial data I have implemented. 
The Issue is that I am calling a function that puts initial data into Firestore every time they sign in with the phone auth, as seen below. I have tried many ways to get around this, but no luck.

```
AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: widget.verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
                    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
                    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
                    await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updatingProfile( // How I put the initialData into Firestore
                      "", 
                      "https://www.nacdnet.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/person-placeholder.jpg",
                      user.phoneNumber
                    );
                    await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updatingStat(""); // How I put the initialData into Firestore
                    return user;
```

#### DatabaseService

```
// Create instance for Firestore collection 
  final CollectionReference _profileCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("profile");
  final CollectionReference _statCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("stat");

  // Updating user profile
  Future updatingProfile(String name, String image, String phoneNumber) async {
  return await _profileCollection.document(uid).setData({
    "name": name,
    "image": image,
    "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
    });
  }

  // Updating user Stat
  Future updatingStat(String stat) async {
    return await _statCollection.document(uid).setData({
      "stat": stat,
      "lastUpdate": DateTime.now()
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does `await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updatingStat("");` do? Please make sure that your question includes the [minimal, complete/standalone code that we can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that worked was by using the `where` method for filtering. I first query all the documents and filter with the phone number field, then go through each document individually to check if they have any documents in firestore, if not, then a new account gets created.

```
    AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: widget.verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    QuerySnapshot resultFromDb = await _db
      .where("phoneNumber", isEqualTo: user.phoneNumber)
      .getDocuments();
       final List<DocumentSnapshot> docsFromDb = resultFromDb.documents;
        if (docsFromDb.length == 0) {
         await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updatingProfile(
          "", 
          "https://www.nacdnet.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/person-placeholder.jpg",
           user.phoneNumber
         );
         await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updatingStat("");
         return user;  
        }
```